# Creating dieline for inkjet printing

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, print-production, packaging, dieline

[image]

I have a dieline for a 3D cube which I will print my own design onto on my inkjet printer.

How is best to print the fold / cutting marks without them interfering with the design? Would I just print them really thin and in a light colour so that the design gets printed over them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally you want any marks outside the printable area.

Really you just need enough marks to know where edges fall. Typically fold/score lines are dashed, while cut lines are solid.

[image]

Using something like the above should allow you to cut things out properly.

Score everything first, which will make where to cut clearer.

[image]

<sub>(Note: The marks on these images may not be aligned 100% accurately. I merely eyeballed alignments to provide an example.)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use a very light gray, let's say 10%. Print a series of thin lines on different color densities and make a choice.

That depends on the design of course.

But probably you should think in cut marks. Those are outside the design.

[image]

If the design is going to be commercially printed, you need to send your pink lines as a separate layer or even a separate file.

And you will use now the cut marks I mentioned to align the design with the cutting.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the document up so the light grey lines are printed on the inside of the box, so when it's folded they are invisble.